# What is the best way make an array out of my data in python?

Tags: python, arraylist

I am new to python and I need help to make/represent an array from this data type.

```
link1|2-3,6-9,12-13|4-5,10-11,14-16
```

The format is `link_name|boundary1|boundary2`
I need to put values `A` to `boundary1` and `B` to `boundary2`

Which should result to this:

```
position :  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
value    :  A A B B A A A A  B B   A  A  B  B  B
```

Comment: btw, the length of the boundaries varies - e.g. 2-78, 100-125, etc. the sample data presented above is for just presentation purposes. hope this helps.

Comment: I think you need to demonstrate an attempt to solve the problem before someone will spend time helping you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
data = data.split('|')[1]
data = data.split(',')
data = [d.split('-') for d in data]
data = [(int(d[0]), int(d[1])) for d in data]

positions = range(2, 17)
values = ['A' if any(data[j][1] >= i >= data[j][0] for j in range(len(data))) else 'B' for i in positions]
```

Basically, any information but the first list of ranges is not needed, because anything which is not 'A' is 'B' by default. I put your ranges data into this format using first four lines of my code:

```
[(2,3), (6,9), (12,13)]
```

and then goes a list comprehension to classify the data.

Comment: when i tried the first 4 lines... an error occurs... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user3267156 print your data and see how it looks. This code works perfectly well with the entry you have provided in your question.

Comment: thanks a lot sashkello, this works perfectly with my database.

Answer (score 1):

While probably not as efficient as the dictionary based approaches, this gets the job done too:

```
data = "link1|2-3,6-9,12-13|4-5,10-11,14-16"
link_name, boundary_1, boundary_2 = data.split("|")
boundary_1 = [(b, "A") for b in boundary_1.split(",")] 
boundary_2 = [(b, "B") for b in boundary_2.split(",")]
temp = boundary_1 + boundary_2
# We sort the temp list based on the starting point
temp = sorted(temp, key=lambda x: int(x[0].split("-")[0]))
position = []
value = []
for pair, letter in temp:
    start, stop = pair.split("-")
    # We loop through all the intermittent values that are not in the input
    for val in range(int(start), int(stop)+1):
        position.append(val)
        value.append(letter)

print "position:\t{}".format("\t".join([str(x) for x in position]))
print "value:   \t{}".format("\t".join([x for x in value]))
```

This generates the output like you requested (with tab separation):

```
position:   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
value:      A   A   B   B   A   A   A   A   B   B   A   A   B   B   B
```

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it solved your problem, because I think some of the other suggestions aren't entirely correct

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like a dictionary.

```
line = "link1|2-3,6-9,12-13|4-5,10-11,14-16"
a, b = line.split("|")[1:] 
a = [item for i in a.split("-") for item in i.split(",")]
b = [item for i in b.split("-") for item in i.split(",")]
data = {k:"A" for k in a}
data.update({k:"B" for k in b})

print data
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need dictionary in python:

```
data = {}
def mapToDict(boundary, value):
    for item in boundary.split(','):
        for position in item.split('-'):
            data[position]=value

s='link1|2-3,6-9,12-13|4-5,10-11,14-16'
items = s.split('|')

mapToDict(items[1],'A')
mapToDict(items[2],'B')

print data
```

Output:

```
{'11': 'B', '10': 'B', '13': 'A', '12': 'A', '14': 'B', '16': 'B', '3': 'A', '2': 'A', '5': 'B', '4': 'B', '6': 'A', '9': 'A'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_lsit(boundry_list):
    list_t = []
    for i in boundry_list:
            l = i.split('-')
            ran = range(eval(l[0]),eval(l[1])+1)
            for j in ran:
                list_t.append(j)
    return list_t

def create_dic(dic,input_list, val):
    for i in input_list:
        dic[i] = val

def get_some(link_name,boundary1,boundary2):
        main_dic = {}
        boundry1 = create_lsit(boundary1.split(','))
        create_dic(main_dic,boundry1, 'a')
        boundry2 = create_lsit(boundary2.split(','))
        create_dic(main_dic,boundry2, 'b')

        for key in sorted(main_dic.keys()):
            print key, '   ', main_dic[key]

data = 'link1|2-3,6-9,12-13|4-5,10-11,14-16'.split('|')     
get_some(data[0],data[1],data[2])
```

This might be lengthy but I think this is what you were looking for.